# Why are there multiple Namespaces for one class?

Tags: .net, namespaces, frameworks, assemblies

So I noticed that I can choose between multiple Namespaces for a Class.

My Class is `Extensions` I can use one of these three Namespaces:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Why is that so? I know that all of those Namespaces have different Methods/Classes/Interfaces/Enums/Delegates.

But why isn´t there something like

```
using System.Xml.Everything;
```

?

Would those different Methods/Classes/Interfaces/Enums/Delegates interfere  each other?

Or is it so everything can be read and managed more easily?

Or both reasons (+ even more)? Or am I completly wrong about everything? :D

Another question I have

```
System.Xml.Linq // Assemblies: System.Xml.XDocument.dll, System.Xml.Linq.dll, netstandard.dll
```

and

```
System.Xml.Schema // Assemblies: System.Xml.Linq.dll, netstandard.dll, System.Xml.XDocument.dll
```

have the same three assemblies. What does it mean here? Are Linq and Schema actually the same (having the same Classes/etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a namespace is to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects.

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

The above 3 namespaces contain different classes that have different responsibilities.

[System.Xml.XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

- Contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model

[System.Xml.Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema?view=netframework-4.7.2)

- Contains the XML classes that provide standards-based support for XML schema definition language (XSD) schemas

[System.Xml.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2)

- Contains the classes for LINQ to XML. LINQ to XML is an in-memory XML programming interface that enables you to modify XML documents efficiently and easily

They may all reference similar assemblies but they require that to complete their task. This is the reason that we split up our code in the first place. **Reusability**.